# extract value between two square braces

Tags: powershell

I need to extract the value between two square braces from a specific line in a command output. Here's the output of the command.

```
C:\Informatica\PowerCenter\isp\bin> .\infacmd.bat ping -dn Infadomain -nn Node01
[INFACMD_10052] Node [Node01] Domain [Infadomain] Host:Port [infadev:6005] was successfully pinged.
[INFACMD_10470] Kerberos authentication is [disabled] and secure communication is [disabled] in the Informatica domain [Infadomain].
Command ran successfully.
```

From the above output, I need to extract the value 'infadev' from the above command result. I tried the regex functions to extract the value but somehow the code does not work.

```
$cmd = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& cmd.exe /c "infacmd.bat ping" -dn "Infadomain" -nn "Node01"}  | Where-Object {$_ -ne 'Command ran successfully.'}
$result = $cmd |(\[(?:\[??[^\[]*?\]))
write-host $result
```

> At line:2 char:17 + $result = $cmd |([(?:[??[^[]*?])) + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline. + CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline

```
invoke-command -ScriptBlock {& cmd.exe /c "infacmd.bat ping" -dn "InfaDomain" -nn "Node01"} | Where-Object {$_ -ne 'Command ran successfully.'}
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: At line:2 char:17
+ $result = $cmd |(\[(?:\[??[^\[]*?\]))
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline

Comment: Don't put information into comments, [edit] the question next time yourself

Comment: `$cmd` cotains the output you pipe to ***WHAT***? A regular expression needs an operator and quotes.

Comment: is `infadev:` always part of that block? if so, it makes things _much_ simpler. [*grin*]

Comment: The value inside the square braces for 'Host:Port' changes each time the command gets executed. It could be 'Host:Port [infatest], 'Host:Port [infaprod]' etc. each time the command runs.

Comment: @signalhouse - thank you for that info! [*grin*] i used it in my answer to build a somewhat simpler regex.

Comment: Thank you for the code snippet. It gave the expected result from the hardcoded command value. However I am just wondering how to get the hostname:port value from the result of a command. For example, I want to run a infacmd.bat command to ping each server and get the hostname and port information back from the command for each server. The command goes like this. invoke-command -ScriptBlock {& cmd.exe /c "infacmd.bat ping" -dn "InfaDomain" -nn "Node01"} | Where-Object {$_ -ne 'Command ran successfully.'}

Comment: Never mind. I got the output I was looking for by tweaking your code a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is another take on the idea. [*grin*] it uses a named capture group to grab the 1st set of bracketed data after the `Host:Port` text.

```
$Cmd = @'
[INFACMD_10052] Node [Node01] Domain [Infadomain] Host:Port [infadev:6005] was successfully pinged.
[INFACMD_10470] Kerberos authentication is [disabled] and secure communication is [disabled] in the Informatica domain [Infadomain].
Command ran successfully.
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$Null = $Cmd.ForEach({$_ -match 'Host:Port \[(?<HostPortInfo>.+)\]'})

$Matches.HostPortInfo
```

output ...

```
infadev:6005
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Where -match` to get array of results, than use `$Matches[i]`.

```
$cmd = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {& cmd.exe /c "infacmd.bat ping" -dn "Infadomain" -nn "Node01"}  | Where-Object {$_ -ne 'Command ran successfully.'}
$cmd | Where {$_ -match "(\[(?:\[??[^\[]*?\]))" }

$result0 = $Matches[0]
$result1 = $Matches[1]
...
```